# Tool for LDAP performance measurement

Tags: performance, ldap

### Question

Has anyone measured performance metrics (read, write, bind, anything) on directory servers? Which tool should I use (instead of writing my own shell script with `ldapsearch`, `ldapbind` and `ldapmodify` commands)?

### Purpose

I'd like to show the degree of performance increase by load balancing between two replicated LDAP instances. Is [OpenDJ's LDAP toolkit](http://opendj.forgerock.org/opendj-ldap-toolkit/) adequate for this purpose?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had successfully deployed and used SLAMD (http://dl.thezonemanager.com/slamd/) for distributed load generation and performance analysis on our LDAP servers. I believe its author, Neil Wilson, no longer supports and/or improves it. The related story is told at the link I provided. Apache JMeter (http://jmeter.apache.org/index.html) can also be used to conduct load generation on LDAP servers and obtain performance metrics.